# $t^p - t -a $ is irreducible if and only if it has no root

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field with characteristic $p$, and $f = t^p -t -a \in F[t]$. Show that $f$ is irreducible if and only if it has no root in $F$.

---

The "only if" part is clear. But how do I show the "if" part? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, but if nobody here answers, you can find this proved in Lang's Algebra.

Comment: @Gaffney Thanks! Can you tell me which page is the proof?

Comment: I think that this is theorem 6.4(ii) on page 290 of my edition.

Comment: I got it! Thanks!